# How can I get only text part out of recognised object in Microsoft Speech Service

Tags: python, azure, nlp, speech-recognition, azure-speech

Following is my output of speech recognition from file from Microsoft Azure Speech SDK. I want to know how can I extract just the 'text' part from this output rather than complete.

> SpeechRecognitionEventArgs(session_id=e28f6907838640e191f214035d69f5e0, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=c27fa5b36bcd466f8162ca3c6ce5f935, **text="Hello good morning, my name is Arihant. How may I help you?"**, reason=ResultReason.RecognizedSpeech))

> CANCELED SpeechRecognitionCanceledEventArgs(session_id=e28f6907838640e191f214035d69f5e0, result=SpeechRecognitionResult(result_id=5681af6a81994a76a11b7e94307c7c2e, text="", reason=ResultReason.Canceled))

> CLOSING on SessionEventArgs(session_id=e28f6907838640e191f214035d69f5e0)

Comment: How does this output occur? The SDK gives you this string? Or you’re outputting it from an object?

Comment: Can you please share your snippet ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is the below code you are using :

```
speech_recognizer.recognized.connect(lambda evt: print('RECOGNIZED: {}'.format(evt)))
```

You could get the text only using `evt.result`